# Connect to Windows CE 6.0 with Windows Mobile over Ethernet

Tags: windows-mobile, ethernet, activesync

I been search the web without any answer.
I'm looking to connect to our device with Windows Mobile, using a computer with Windows7 to our device running Windows CE6.0. It works if i connect with USB, however in the future our new PC card won't have any USB Client port on the device which makes this impossible.

Is there some way to do the same thing over Ethernet?
Greetings

Comment: Define "connect".  If the device and the PC are on the same network then they are connected.  Are you asking if you can do something like WMDC over Ethernet?

Comment: I been using ActiveSync before on a WinXP computer, but since i got Win7 have I been using Windows Mobile to connect to our device that have WinCE6.0 and ActiveSync to debugg the system. I terminate some services on the device and can debugg live. Im using a USB Client port on the device for this, and I would like to connect over Ethernet instead if this is possible?

Comment: Y, to your Q. WMDC over Ethernet instead of USB Client

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're asking is how to debug your application over Ethernet (correct me if I'm wrong).  If that's what you're after then yes, you can do it using CoreCon manually.  [The steps are outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708.aspx).

The process requires running `ConManClient2.exe` and `CMAccept.exe` on the device.  How that's done is up to you, and there's no "one way" to do it.  Yu might run it from a shell app like Explorer.  Maybe from a command-line console.  You could set them to run by putting them in the Startup folder, or adjusting the `HKLM\Init` registry entries to auto-run them at startup.

In any case, it's likely you'll only need this during development, so an easy way is to use something like an Explorer shell.  Boot the device, explore and run the apps, then do your debugging.  When you go to ship the app, disable, remove or replace the shell app and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I don't have access to the command prompt which is an issue. With the USB Client I'm connected and terminate the process that is running, and start them from my computer using VS2008 and can debugg it from there. If i would add command prompt to the device, it would remain there which isn't wanted.